# Reading a Specific JSON Column for Tokenization

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am planning to tokenize a column within a JSON file with NLTK. The code below reads and slices the JSON file according into different time intervals.

I am however struggling to have the `'Main Text'` column (within the JSON file) read/tokenized in the final part of the code below. Is there any smart tweak to make this happen?

```
# Loading and reading dataset
file = open("Glassdoor_A.json", "r")
data = json.load(file)
df = pd.json_normalize(data)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])


# Create an empty dictionary
d = dict()


# Filtering by date
start_date = pd.to_datetime('2009-01-01')
end_date = pd.to_datetime('2009-03-31')
last_end_date = pd.to_datetime('2017-12-31')
mnthBeg = pd.offsets.MonthBegin(3)
mnthEnd = pd.offsets.MonthEnd(3)
while end_date <= last_end_date:
    filtered_dates = df[df.Date.between(start_date, end_date)]
    n = len(filtered_dates.index)
    print(f'Date range: {start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")} - {end_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")},  {n} rows.')
    if n > 0:
        print(filtered_dates)
    start_date += mnthBeg
    end_date += mnthEnd


# NLTK tokenizing
file_content = open('Main Text').read()
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(file_content)
print(tokens)
```

Comment: What is the 'Main Text' column referring to?

Comment: It's a string text of several lines. The JSON file itself has the following structure: `[
{"No":"121","Stock Symbol":"A","Date":"05/11/2017","Text Main":"Sample text"}
]`

Comment: Hey, not sure what the problem is. What is the output you're getting and what do you expect?

Comment: I am getting the output `file_content = open('Main Text').read(), FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Main Text'` - apologies for not specifying that in the question. The problem is that I am trying to tokenize a column within the JSON file, not the entire file...

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the situation with the following code, which runs smoothly. Many thanks again for everyone's input.

```
    for index, row in filtered_dates.iterrows():
        line = row['Text Main']
        tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(line)
        print(tokens)
```